# Commerce ogone running on ogone page but not in drupal side

Tags: commerce

I installed the commerce_ogone module on Drupal 7 with Drupal commerce modules in local environment.

**First shop, first case :**

1. I set my payment method to my test account (PSID, sha in, sha out). When I chose Ogone in the cart I was redirected to ogone page. I set test credit card number and I validated.
2. At this moment, Ogone told me that "Your payment is authorized". Next I was redirected to the review page of the Drupal cart. On this page I have the message "Payment failed at the payment server. Please review your information and try again." but there is nothing in Drupal log.
3. I also received an email from ingenico test with my order but I can see that sentence : "This transaction must be confirmed manually in the administration module to generate a payment."

But I don't know how and why I need to confirm manually ?

**Second shop, second case :**

1. Same as above.
2. Same as above but there is the following message in error log : "SHA signature doesn't match feedback".
3. Ogone told me by email that there is a problem with the http request. The error is "Error in HTTP response - http result = -1" but there is nothing about this error inside the list of all error code of Ogone.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the list of parameters that are used in sha1 in the function `commerce_ogone_sha1_out_parameters`. I found a patch in this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2736531 and it solved the problem.

```
diff --git a/commerce_ogone.sha1.inc b/commerce_ogone.sha1.inc
index dbf7096..9ee45f1 100644
--- a/commerce_ogone.sha1.inc
+++ b/commerce_ogone.sha1.inc
@@ -31,13 +31,16 @@ function commerce_ogone_feedback_valid_sha1($feedback, $sha1out) {
  *   SHA1-OUT security hash.
  */
 function commerce_ogone_sha1_out_parameters() {
-  return array('AAVADDRESS', 'AAVCHECK', 'AAVZIP', 'ACCEPTANCE', 'ALIAS', 'AMOUNT',
-    'BIN', 'BRAND', 'CARDNO', 'CCCTY', 'CN', 'COMPLUS', 'CREATION_STATUS', 'CURRENCY',
-    'CVC', 'CVCCHECK', 'DCC_COMMPERCENTAGE', 'DCC_CONVAMOUNT', 'DCC_CONVCCY',
-    'DCC_EXCHRATE', 'DCC_EXCHRATESOURCE', 'DCC_EXCHRATETS', 'DCC_INDICATOR',
-    'DCC_MARGINPERCENTAGE', 'DCC_VALIDHOURS', 'DIGESTCARDNO', 'ECI', 'ED',
-    'ENCCARDNO', 'IP', 'IPCTY', 'NBREMAILUSAGE', 'NBRIPUSAGE',
-    'NBRIPUSAGE_ALLTX', 'NBRUSAGE', 'NCERROR', 'NCERRORCARDNO', 'NCERRORCN',
-    'NCERRORCVC', 'NCERRORED', 'ORDERID', 'PAYID', 'PM', 'SCO_CATEGORY',
-    'SCORING', 'STATUS', 'SUBBRAND', 'SUBSCRIPTION_ID', 'TRXDATE', 'VC');
+  return array('AAVADDRESS', 'AAVCHECK', 'AAVMAIL', 'AAVNAME', 'AAVPHONE',
+    'AAVZIP', 'ACCEPTANCE', 'ALIAS', 'AMOUNT', 'BIC', 'BIN', 'BRAND', 'CARDNO',
+    'CCCTY', 'CN', 'COLLECTOR_BIC', 'COLLECTOR_IBAN', 'COMPLUS',
+    'CREATION_STATUS', 'CREDITDEBIT', 'CURRENCY', 'CVCCHECK',
+    'DCC_COMMPERCENTAGE', 'DCC_CONVAMOUNT', 'DCC_CONVCCY', 'DCC_EXCHRATE',
+    'DCC_EXCHRATESOURCE', 'DCC_EXCHRATETS', 'DCC_INDICATOR',
+    'DCC_MARGINPERCENTAGE', 'DCC_VALIDHOURS', 'DEVICEID', 'DIGESTCARDNO', 'ECI',
+    'ED', 'EMAIL', 'ENCCARDNO', 'FXAMOUNT', 'FXCURRENCY', 'IP', 'IPCTY',
+    'MANDATEID', 'MOBILEMODE', 'NBREMAILUSAGE', 'NBRIPUSAGE',
+    'NBRIPUSAGE_ALLTX', 'NBRUSAGE', 'NCERROR', 'ORDERID', 'PAYID', 'PAYIDSUB',
+    'PAYMENT_REFERENCE', 'PM', 'SCO_CATEGORY', 'SCORING', 'SEQUENCETYPE',
+    'SIGNDATE', 'STATUS', 'SUBBRAND', 'SUBSCRIPTION_ID', 'TRXDATE', 'VC');
 }
```